# Updating listview content when online

Tags: android, json, listview, caching

I am taking data from json using volley and I want to add data to cache. I added to cache, it works fine in offline mode, but when it's online mode each data doubled because of fetching data from json api. So my question is how can show my cache data to the user until fetching json data then displaying new one and updating cache also with new data.

Here is my code reading cached data and fetching online data:

```
     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);


    list1=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.kunlist);
    list2=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.oylist);
    list3=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.haflist);
    listitem=new ArrayList<>();
    itemList2=new ArrayList<>();
    itemList3=new ArrayList<>();
    loadfirst();
    loadingView();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return v;
}

private void loadingView() {

    StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_Data,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject array=jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");


                        ObjectOutput out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(activity2.getCacheDir(),"")+File.separator+"cache.srl"));
                        out.writeObject(array.toString());
                        out.close();

                   jsonRead(array);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Activity activity = getActivity();
                    if(activity != null && isAdded()&&getContext()!=null)
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Internet problem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

  public void loadfirst(){
    try{
        ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(activity2.getCacheDir()+File.separator+"cache.srl")));

 JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject((String)in.readObject());
        in.close();
        jsonRead(jObject);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void jsonRead(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    JSONArray day=obj.getJSONArray("day");
    JSONArray week=obj.getJSONArray("week");
    JSONArray month=obj.getJSONArray("month");

    KunItem item=null;
    KunItem kun=null;
    KunItem hafta=null;
    for(int i=0;i<day.length();i++) {
        JSONObject o = day.getJSONObject(i);

        if (Tab1.this.res.getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals("uz")) {
            item = new KunItem(
                    o.getString("name_uz"),
                    o.getString("price"),
                    o.getString("activation_code")
            );

        } else if (Tab1.this.res.getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals("ru")) {

            item = new KunItem(
                    URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(o.getString("name_ru"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"),
                    o.getString("price"),
                    o.getString("activation_code"));

        }

        listitem.add(item);
        adapter = new KunAdapter(context, listitem);

        list1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<week.length();i++) {
        JSONObject o = week.getJSONObject(i);

        if (Tab1.this.res.getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals("uz")) {

            kun = new KunItem(
                    o.getString("name_uz"),
                    o.getString("price"),
                    o.getString("activation_code")
            );
        }
        else if (Tab1.this.res.getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals("ru")) {

            kun = new KunItem(

                    URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(o.getString("name_ru"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"),
                    o.getString("price"),
                    o.getString("activation_code"));


        }

        itemList2.add(kun);
        adapter2 = new KunAdapter(context, itemList2);
        list3.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<month.length();i++) {
        JSONObject o = month.getJSONObject(i);

        if (Tab1.this.res.getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals("uz")) {

            hafta = new KunItem(
                    o.getString("name_uz"),
                    o.getString("price"),
                    o.getString("activation_code")
            );


        } else if (Tab1.this.res.getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage().equals("ru")) {
            hafta = new KunItem(

                    URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(o.getString("name_ru"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"),
                    o.getString("price"),
                    o.getString("activation_code")
            );
        }
        itemList3.add(hafta);
        adapter3=new KunAdapter(context,itemList3);

        list2.setAdapter(adapter3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do this

1- Displayed listview through Data from internal database (If there is)

2- fetch new data from server

3- Clear the previous data in the internal database (If done successfully)

4- save New data in the internal database

5- Show fetched data to user with listview

Comment: Yes, you are right! I did it already, I am having trouble on displaying data in listview when online, it shows offline data and fetched data from server together). Do you have any suggestions for that!
And one more question: how can I delete previous data in the internal database?

Comment: Yes
When you fetch new data from the server, before , clear the list ,  and then fill the list and notifyDataSetChange adapter.

Comment: That was helpful!